# How to write code to modify itself with fopen() and fseek()?

Tags: php

I trying to write code to modifies itself with "fopen()" and "fseek()".

I manage to add code as in the example below, but I'm just recovering the contents of the file by adding an echo "test"; everytime.

```
<?php 

$recup = file_get_contents('index.php');

$recup .= 'echo "test ";';

file_put_contents('index.php', $recup);
echo "test ";echo "test ";echo "test ";echo "test ";
```

How can I write code with fopen() and fseek() to modify which modifies itself to increment a variable containing an integer for example?

Comment: Self-modifying code is probably unwise ;)  ALTERNATIVES: 1) just declare a simple variable (ideal, if possible), 2) declare a PHP session variable or (last resort) 3) use an external data store (read and update a text file, use a database, etc).

Comment: This would only work if an external mechanism (i.e. cronjob) executes the code again afterwards. May I ask what you are trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: there is not really a goal behind, it's just out of curiosity, I just wondered if the use of fopen () and fseek () allowed this.

Comment: In addition to @FoggyDay's comment on how legendarily bad an idea self-modifying code is, as far as in-place file modification goes the best you can do is overwrite bytes. Eg: your file contains `foo bar baz` and you want to write `bagel` in place of `baz` your file is now `foo bagelaz`. Generally you want to write an entirely new file, remove the old one, and point the filename at the new file.

Comment: fopen will open your php file like file_get_contents, fseek just moves pointer at some position, 
and as i understood you want to read some integer and increment, so you have to find it somehow. Its easier to deal with strings (like str_replace) or find and replace it with  regexps, or if you know exact byte positions to read from, but then again you will have an issue with replacing it with new incremented value, then you want to rewrite full content of file with file_put_contents() 
but, yes, its technically possible,
your example looks confusing, it doesn't reflect example with integer.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here to a self-modifying file is that you want to both execute code as well as write to the file that's executing that code at the same time.

This is possible with just a little bit ingenuity. The approach is to modify the file in memory or on disk temporarily such that you can modify its code and rewrite it.

Once, rewritten, however, it will work as expect upon further execution.

```
<?php
function update() {
    $file = file(__FILE__);
    $tmpFile = array_slice($file, 0, 28);

    $tmpFile = implode($tmpFile);
    $file = "<?php\n" . array_pop($file);

    $tmpName = tempnam("/tmp", "selfmodifyingphp");
    file_put_contents($tmpName, $file);

    $r = include $tmpName; unlink($tmpName);
    file_put_contents($tmpName, $tmpFile . $file);
    yield $r;

    $file = file(__FILE__);
    array_pop($file);
    $file[] = "return " . (++$r) . ";\n";
    $file = implode($file);
    file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
    yield;
}
$num = update();
$int = $num->current();
if (empty($int)) {
    $int = 1;
}
echo $int, "\n\n";
$num->next();
return 1;
```

Each time you run this code it will increment the output of `$int` by one. This is because we write to a temporary file the contents of the file's last line and then include it, modify its value, and rewrite back to the current file.

Now the caveat here is that POSIX doesn't overwrite the file on disk as long as there are open file handles (we're running it in php so it's open for as long as the code is executing). However, once the script ends. The file will be written to disk and thus upon next time you run it in php the value will change.

You can of course refine this approach using `fopen`/`fseek` as discussed in the comments, to point to a very specific position in the file and rewrite the value, but this leaves a lot of room for error especially if the size of the input/output changes over time. So instead I prefer the approach of modifying entire lines in the file at a time as lines have no width constraints. Dealing with the height constraint is a little easier if you plan things just right and don't change height over time, which is possible by writing multiple statements to the same line.

A part of the tricks used in this code is the use of a generator as a co-routine to delay the part of the code that reads the code from the part that writes to the file such that we don't run into any race conditions. Notice the part that executes the code removes the function otherwise we'd get a "*Can't redeclare function*" error.

> Note you should probably only run this script from CLI, as you don't want to expose self-modifying code to the web (*as an exercise anyway*). If you do run it from a web SAPI you should probably take opcode caching into consideration here and invalidate any opcode cache just incase file mtime is not affected.